# How do I search for something when I'm searching for something?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Refactoring can be a recursive process.

First I need to replace some file, so I search the entire workspace for instances of some class or string.

[image]

There's 100+ results that I start going through.

As I'm getting through those I see something, maybe a mini project. Now I need to go and search something else.

The way I currently handle this is ridiculous:

1. Open Typora, write down what I was refactoring and my progress through that list of search results
2. Search the new thing / handle the new thing
3. Go back to my old search

This is ridiculous because a search-all-files search allows you to ignore and "x"-out individual files. So I lose a lot of progress when this happens.

Is there a way to open a second magnifying glass on the left or somehow leave that search where it is and search something else?

Comment: It sounds like the _process_ is the problem. If you depart on some other tangent mid-refactor, you're never back in a testable state until _both_ are complete. Note down the _tangent_, and return to it when the refactor is complete.

Comment: In this specific case I am renaming a database column. One of the 100 things I need to update/migrate is a library that's probably no longer used. So here it would be nice to confirm not used (a simple search) and delete it rather than performing migration.